# Standard Deviation calculations

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

C[[image: Pic1][1]]Calculate the mean and standard deviation of each investment, assume that both returns come from independent samples, are both normally distributed and that the (true but unknown) variances are the same,, Can someone could check my calculations for mean and standard deviation? I did calculations but not sure what to do with negative values of distances(If if am correct Investment A MEAN= 78.6875 when it comes to calculating standard deviation i have to power difference by 2 ?

[image]